# Delphi AV vs Try-Except

Tags: delphi, architecture, error-handling, try-catch

Good day!

I have a multi-threads application with TaskManager, workers... And i have a problem.

threads execute-method looks like:

```
try
 task.execute();
except
 on E : Exception do
 begin
   log(e.message);
   //  callResetThread/disconnectUser
 end;
end;
```

Each task have many Access Violations, runtime errors... Try-except for some cases does not 
help. Is there any solution for protect my program from the errors at threads...

Delphi 7/ no jedi/ default memory-managers

**UPDATE**

Dear friends! 
We have a code with many third-party components. This program raised 1-2 exception per week in single user mode. When we modify this program to work in server-mode with equal 500 clients we can have > **70 exceptions per day** (1-2 may be critical and not catched try ... except ...end). 
**We realy understand that we must fix all bugs** :-). But source code (with third-party components) has size > 20 Mb...
We realy need your help, HOW WE CAN CATCH THIS SYSTEM ERRORS (may be with using system methods).

Comment: I suspect your "callResetThread/disconnectUser" is raising the A/V.

Comment: Access Violations occur when you read or write to invalid memory addresses. Simply put, stop doing so!

Comment: no,no - it's very safety function. And i have error without that lines.

Comment: I can not catch all the situations that lead to error... task.execute() is over 100 000 lines of sources

Comment: To summarize this, you've got 100 000 lines of code throwing exceptions in 9 000 different places. That is, 1 in every 11 lines of code might throw an exception. And this is going at the rate of 1 exception every 20 minutes. And that code is supporting 500 clients. I don't think you're honest, so I'll give a -1. Good luck finding the silver bullet.

Comment: These so called system errors are almost certainly errors in your code

Comment: A close vote from me as well. "Show me how to hide my problem" isn't a real question.

Comment: First kill all your try/except workarounds. Then look carefully at text in error dialogs shown. If you are lucky your search for string parts of this text will show results in sources of components you use. Then you will be able to locate part of the component that needs to be modified. Even better replace that component with better alternative. This was the solution for one of my OPC servers that had strange errors after heavy working on a server for 2-3 weeks. It was buggy AsyncPro TCP client component.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You **HAVE** to fix them **ALL**, really! The AV is not only a problem of the exception an the handling of it. Every exception (AV) throws you programm into some more or less "undefined" state, because your code tried to write or read some data into/from memory and the data is not valid. So the result of your App or the thing it is supposed to do is not working! And there is no "it is not possible"! It is for sure possible or you have to rewrite the code...

Answer (score 15):

Try-except isn't *supposed* to "help" with runtime errors. *You're* supposed to help by **fixing the bugs in your program** so that the access violations and other errors don't occur in the first place.

If an exception occurs and you don't know why, then there's nothing you can do in your program to fix the problem, so there's no reason for your program to continue running. For all you know, your program's memory is already corrupted, so the safest thing you can do is to terminate the program so as not put your customers' data in any more danger.

If a try-except block isn't catching exceptions, then either your program is *so* broken that you've overwritten the part of your program that handles exceptions, or the exceptions are occurring outside the try-except block.

You can try using an exception-logging library such as MadExcept, EurekaLog, or JclDebug. They detect exceptions in your program and record information to help you debug the problems.

Another possibility is that the *debugger* is interrupting your program when an exception occurs and showing you a message about it. That's the debugger, not your program, so if you then let your program keep running, you'll see your exception-handling code take over.

Comment: I know why program corrupted, i know why and where i get access violetion and other errors. but it's over 9000 cases. I will fix popular bugs, and i need in mechanism for catching many unpopular errors.  P.S. is not debbuger problem

Comment: Over 9000 known places where access violations occur? Ouch. Anyway, there's no real alternative to fixing them...

Comment: @TheHorse Stop pretending that you can get away with this and start fixing your bugs.

Comment: If "fix the bugs" is not a solution, then I fear nothing is.

Comment: @TheHorse: you are not serius about that, aren't you? 9000 places with an AV! It semms like a miracle to me, that this piece of buggy code does something useful at all! Fix them, there is no alternative!

Comment: I'm sorry, couldn't resist: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SiMHTK15Pik On topic: I think you really should fix just all of them. If you know where the bugs are, fix them. Use `try..excepts` for the unexpected, not the unpopular ones.

Answer (score 5):

The only way for you to get higher resilience than `try`/`except` is to use separate processes (and after that, separate machines, then separate datacentres, etc.).

It sounds like the code you are using was not designed to be used with threads, never mind the heavy multi-threading that you'll see in a server application. I don't think your current approach is workable.